# Error: conflicting parameter types in implementation NS_ENUM

Tags: objective-c

I'm using a custom protocol in  my view controller and one of its required methods takes a NS_ENUM type called PunchState.

```
#import "globals.h"

@protocol PunchViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) punchViewDidChangeState:(PunchState) newState;
-(void) punchViewDidChangeTimerStartTimeTo:(CFAbsoluteTime) newTime;

@end
```

PunchState is defined in globals.h like so...

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PunchState)
{
    PunchStateStarting =1,
    PunchStateWorking,
    PunchStateBreaking,
    PunchStateLunching,
    PunchStateEnding,
};
```

Problem is that whenever I try to use create the protocol method in my delegate it changes it from a ***PunchState*** variable as declared in the protocol, to an ***id*** like this.

```
- (void)punchViewDidChangeState:(id)newState
{
    self.currentState = (PunchState) newState;
}
```

Now it will work as is, but i'm wondering why I couldn't just use this:

```
- (void)punchViewDidChangeState:(PunchState)newState
{
    self.currentState = (PunchState) newState;
}
```

Whenever I try I get the error in Question. Any thoughts or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No repro, completes as PunchState for me.